# Error #5: Unaligned word memory reference

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-alignment, mars-simulator

I am attempting to build an array of integers to represent edges (index of source | index of destination | weight) in an implementation of Dijkstra’s Algorithm using MIPS.

On running with rsim, I am getting an “unaligned word memory reference” error. I think I may be misunderstanding what memory alignment refers to. My .data is below

```
.data
.align 4

enterNode:          .asciiz "Enter the number of nodes: "
enterEdges:         .asciiz "Enter the number of edges: "
enterSource:        .asciiz "Enter source: "
enterDestination:   .asciiz "Enter destination: "
enterWeight:        .asciiz "Enter weight: "
newLine:            .asciiz "\n"
min_nodes:          .word 1
max_nodes:          .word 20
error1:             .asciiz "Invalid number of nodes. Must be between 1 and 20.\n"
error2:             .asciiz "Invalid number of edges. Must be between 0 and 400.\n"
edgeArr:            .space 4800
    # source | destination | weight
input:              .space 5
```

In the .text, I am looping for the number of edges to input the data into the array, but it seems the way I am referring to or calculating the address is incorrect.

```
addi    $t0, $zero, 0                   # Edge counter
la      $t1, edgeArr
addi    $t2, $zero, 0

loop:
    # Source
    addi    $v0, $zero, PRINT_STRING    # Print user prompt
    la      $a0, enterSource
    syscall
    addi    $v0, $zero, READ_INT        # Take user input
    syscall
    add     $t3, $t2, $t2               # Calculate address in array
    add     $t3, $t3, $t3
    add     $t3, $t1, $t3
    sw      $v0, ($t3)
    addi    $t2, $t2, 1

    # ...destination and weight are effectively identical to source...

    # Loop condition
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    slt     $t4, $t0, $s1
    bne     $t4, $zero, loop
```

I’ve looked at several similar questions but they don’t seem to quite address the portion I’m misunderstanding, and I could really benefit from a fresh pair of eyes looking at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some strings between the `.align 4` and your `.space` directive.  ([`.word` implicitly aligns by 4 in classic MIPS assemblers like MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926448/mars-mips-simulators-built-in-assembler-aligns-more-than-requested), but `.space` doesn't.)

`.align 4` pads to make the current position a multiple of `2^4 = 16`.  (You probably want `.align 2` to get 1<<2 = 4 byte alignment).  **The total size of the strings are not a multiple of 4, so your `.space` directives are not at word-aligned memory addresses.**

**Fix this by putting the word-aligned objects first, then the odd-length data.**

```
.data
.align 4
min_nodes:          .word 1
max_nodes:          .word 20

edgeArr:            .space 4800
    # source | destination | weight
input:              .space 5              # 5 bytes??


enterNode:          .asciiz "Enter the number of nodes: "
enterEdges:         .asciiz "Enter the number of edges: "
enterSource:        .asciiz "Enter source: "
enterDestination:   .asciiz "Enter destination: "
enterWeight:        .asciiz "Enter weight: "
newLine:            .asciiz "\n"
error1:             .asciiz "Invalid number of nodes. Must be between 1 and 20.\n"
error2:             .asciiz "Invalid number of edges. Must be between 0 and 400.\n"
```

---

If `min_nodes` is a build-time constant, define it with `.equ` instead of storing it in memory at all.  (So you can use it as an immediate constant)

```
.equ  min_nodes, 1
.equ  max_nodes, 20

...
li   $t0, min_modes
```

Or `sltiu $t1, $t0, min_modes` to set `$t1=1` if `$t0 < min_nodes` (unsigned), otherwise set it to zero.  And BTW, you can do a range check with only one branch:

```
addui  $t1, $t0, -1
then compare against 19 (unsigned)
```

Values less than 1 will wrap to a large unsigned value (and compare greater than 19).  Values greater than 20 will still be greater than 19.

---

You also don't need to mix your string constants with read-write values.  If your assembler supports a `.rodata` or `.section .rodata`, your read-only strings go in the text segment of your executable so they're write-protected.

IIRC, MARS doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for. I hadn’t thought about where I was declaring the arrays. I’ll also make sure to change the min and max nodes. You’re correct in that they are simply constants and that would probably be a better way of declaring them. I’m not sure if the assembler supports .rodata but I will look into the documentation. Thank you!