# How do I input a string into the text segment instead of the data segment in assembly (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, segment

I have an assignment in which I am asked to change each lowercase letter of a given string to an uppercase letter.

My problem is that the professor has asked us to input the string into the text segment and not the data segment.

I have tried using `lw` and `sw` but it doesn't work.
Is there any other way?
(My program works when the string is in the data segment)

This is what I have so far:

```
        .data    
str:    .space 100

textlow:    .asciiz "This is a sample text!"

        .text

main:
        li $t0, 0

loop:

lb $t1, textlow($t0)    
        beq $t1, 0, exit       
        blt $t1, 'a', diff  
        bgt $t1, 'z', diff

sub $t1, $t1, 32  
        sb $t1, textlow($t0)  


diff: 
        addi $t0, $t0, 1

j loop

exit:
        li $v0, 10      
        syscall
```

Comment: What errors do you get, exactly?  Is it an alignment error for the code?  (MIPS instructions have to be aligned on a 4B boundary).  If so, put `.align 4` after the string literal.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482102/error-5-unaligned-word-memory-reference

Comment: Typically, the text segment is read-only. Trying to write to a string in the text segment causes your program to crash.

Comment: Do you want to put the `textlow` string constant into the text segment, or do you also want to put `str: .space 100` in the text segment?  If the latter, you might have to make an `mprotect` system call, unless your emulator has memory protection disabled.

Comment: I want to put the textlow string into the text segment. My professor is also prone to 'testing' us so I've begun to think that it's a trick question because it really doesn't make sense

Comment: I believe you are supposed to produce the output in `str`. So yeah, you can put `textlow` into `.text` because it's gonna be read only.

Comment: Could you give me a code example of that?

Comment: Don't `sb $t1, textlow($t0)`, rather, `sb $t1, str($t0)`

Answer (score 0):

use smc option.

https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/MarsHelpCommand.html

example:

```
java Mars4_5.jar smc mips1.asm
```